# Backbone-Relational: Does fetch trigger change event for all loaded relations

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I did some reading and learned that `fetch`ing a collection triggers the `reset` event for the collection and `change` event for existing model that changed.

In my backbone app, I `fetch` a collection and various relations (`pages` -> `partials` -> `variables`). But when I do, the `change` event is triggered for `partials` and `variables`, which is not what I want, they are only loaded.. Not changed!

Am I doing something wrong or is this default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging in the source, I found out it does. It does a `change:[key]` event.. I added `silent:true` to my fetch, so it skips the event triggers.